# AndroidManifest mismatch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I think I have some `AndroidManifest` mismatch. When I try to build with `Gradle`, I get this

```
[/home/TryIt/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:3, /var/folders/_h/gq0mh1154p76krbwrkj75qbm0000gn/T/manifestMerge2745402073170024437.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion='18'> but library uses targetSdkVersion='19'
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

In the `library` manifest I have `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>` and its `build.gradle` sets

```
compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
```

On the other hand in the `app/src/main/AndroidManifest` manifest I have `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />`

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran a similar issue with some project when updating my `Android-Studio` to the last version. Try to set the `targetSdkVersion` to `19` in all your `gradle` files

Answer (score 2):

In gradle build system the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` will be replaced by what you define in your build.gradle file, so I recommend you to remove `<uses-sdk />` from `AndroidManifest.xml` and keep them in only `build.gradle` files to avoid confusions.

You are getting merging failed error because the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in different modules are not equal. **`minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion must be equal in all build.gradle files inside a project`**.

**EDIT :**

**Note :** Don't set `minSdkVersion = 7` to anywhere because most of the libraries like Google Play Services and all are using `minSdkVersion =8`.  So try to use `minSdkVersion = 8` everywhere in you app.

Check your **`Gradle Console`** output for detailed report of conflicts. It will show which files in the project are cause of this error.

Comment: Sorry I ran `find . -name "build.gradle"` and all files I found seem to be correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and the simple answer is because I had `minSdkVersion 4` in my `build.gradle`.

Changing it to `minSdkVersion 8` 8 fixed this for me.